# Missing value delimiter at position

Tags: java, csv, delimiter

I am getting 'Missing value delimiter at position 1' error while importing CSV file with Java.

Here is my code:

```
 protected int getFieldCount() 
{       
    return 3;
}
protected void importRecord(List<String> record, int lineNumber) {
 String rawScore = record.get(ELEMENT_RAW_SCORE).trim();
 String contextScore = record.get(ELEMENT_CONTEXT).trim();
 String subtest = record.get(ELEMENT_SUBTEST).trim();
}
```

if my csv file looks like this:

```
95,Performance Scale,codes,       
ME,Performance Scale,Numbers,test
NM,Scale,Strategies,
```

When I am leaving extra character in one of the lines as there is "test" in Line 2, I am getting the error, otherwise the import runs fine. The error shows up for each line even if I am only adding to one of the lines.

The `getFieldCount()` method returns int the expected number of fields that should be present in each record in the source file, or a non-positive value if the number of fields is not strictly enforced.

The string methods like `split("\t")` don't work as it is not the tab delimiter causing this issue. The code doesn't stop reading after the column 3, even when I strictly imposed it. How can I tell it not read anything after the column 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you read the csv data, but your csv has 4 columns, not 3:

```
95,Performance Scale,codes,       
ME,Performance Scale,Numbers,test
NM,Scale,Strategies,
```

Line 1 and 3 have an empty value for the fourth column, but this counts as a column.

So maybe try to return 4 for the fieldcount:

```
protected int getFieldCount() 
{       
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: I was editing the csv file in the Excel and when I am adding a character in the 4th column, Excel automatically adds comma's for each row. But I want my program to  skip chars after it encounters 3rd delimiter in each record  per line and if there are only 2 delimiters, don't skip anything.

Comment: @HarpreetSidhu Well, it depends on how the rows are read. If you are using a csv reader you probably get the error because the reader/parser encountered a fourth field where only 3 are given as a fieldcount. I would just return the right fieldcount (4 in this case) and only process the first 3 in `importRecord()`. Or maybe return -1 (as you mention in your post) as the fieldcount to force some kind of auto detect.

Comment: @ Danny_ds,  I tried by returning 4 and it works if there is extra column but not if only 3 columns in the source file. I guess, I need to modify the getFieldCount() to accommodate variable no. of columns and only use the ones I need in the importRecord() method. Thanks @Danny_ds, your ideas were helpful !

Comment: @HarpreetSidhu Yes, it looks like the reader you are using wants the exact field count.